# cannot convert from UIKit.UIImage to ZXing.LuminanceSource - Xamarin iOS in Visual Studios 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, zxing, zbar

All the examples I see are for Xamarin Forms, nothing for Xamarin for Visual Studios. I have an iOS app I'm developing with Xamarin for Visual Studio and need to read barcodes. I downloaded ZBar into Visual Studio 2017 from NuGet and installed it, no problem there. I access the camera and capture an image (barcode), no problem. However, there seems to be no way to convert the UIKit.UIIMage captured from the camera to a "ZXing.LuminanceSource" so it can be decoded. If someone could help point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. The code I have is fairly simple taken from the ZBar example included with the download:

```
IBarcodeReader scanPage = new BarcodeReader();

var result = scanPage.Decode(theImage); // the image is public and is set to the image returned by the camera.  It's here I get the error in intellisense "cannot convert from UIKit.UIImage to ZXing.LuminanceSource"
```

Camera image return code:

```
    [Foundation.Export("imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:")]
    public void FinishedPickingImage(UIKit.UIImagePickerController picker, UIKit.UIImage image, Foundation.NSDictionary editingInfo)
    {
        theImage = MaxResizeImage(image, 540f, 960f);
        picker.DismissModalViewController(false);

    }

    [Foundation.Export("imagePickerControllerDidCancel:")]
    public void Canceled(UIKit.UIImagePickerController picker)
    {
        DismissViewController(true, null);
    }

    public static UIImage MaxResizeImage(UIImage sourceImage, float maxWidth, float maxHeight)
    {
        var sourceSize = sourceImage.Size;
        var maxResizeFactor = Math.Min(maxWidth / sourceSize.Width, maxHeight / sourceSize.Height);
        if (maxResizeFactor > 1) return sourceImage;
        var width = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Width;
        var height = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Height;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize((nfloat)width, (nfloat)height));
        sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, (nfloat)width, (nfloat)height));
        var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return resultImage;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are taking a picture of a barcode, and then attempting to decode it?  Why not just let ZXing do all of that work for you?

Comment: Well, I thought I was.  I was just following the example given on their website.  So what should I be doing?

Comment: look at https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile - the first usage example shows how to scan using 2-3 lines of code

Comment: I'm coding for an iPad, I assume that matters, no?  I'm using ZXing.net.

Comment: no, that doesn't matter.  ZXing.net will handle it

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I added ZXing.Net.Mobile to my project, added `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();` to AppDelegate FinishedLaunching and now I get `'The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing'`.

Comment: If you are not using Forms do not use the Forms version of the pkg

Comment: Actually, adding `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` resolved the issue, see here https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue with some help from @Jason, thanks Jason.  I downloaded from NuGet and installed ZXing.Net.Mobile AND ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.  You need both for Xamarin - Visual Studios.  Removed all that camera code and replaced with 3 lines of code, plus I needed to add `async` to my button_TouchUpInside call.

In AppDelegate FinishedLaunching:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

        // Add this line to initialize ZXing

        ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();

        return true;
    }
```

Changed the button code to this, make button `async` to `await` scan result:

```
    async partial void ScanBarCode_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
       // Create scanner
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();

        // Store result of scan in var result, need to await scan
        var result = await scanner.Scan();

        // display bar code number in text field
        Textbox_BarCode.Text = result.Text;
    }
```

Works every time (thus far).